# MVC app doesn't send email when deployed on a remote server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7.5, web-deployment

When an exception occurs in my MVC app, my code sends an email.

The thing works like a charm when I deploy locally. On the remote server, though, it doesn't send any email.

Below are some details about my deployment environment.

**Web Server:** IIS 7.5

**.NET Framework:** v4

**MVC version:** 4

**Windows Server:** Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Help appreicated.

Comment: Are you able to send mail from that server? Do you have the mail pick directory, or SMTP server specified correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I realized that I had to grant permissions to the user **ASP.NET v4.0**, which was the name of the **Application Pool** / **Identity** under which my application was registered / running.

That solved the problem.